# How can I see emails sent from Marketing Cloud on Salesforce Records other than the who coming from journeys?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, data, sales-cloud

I have read this thread : [How can I see emails sent from Marketing Cloud on Salesforce Records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169580/how-can-i-see-emails-sent-from-marketing-cloud-on-salesforce-records/171837#171837?newreg=bb2f685938574d8199a7eeefe3175698), but the method seems to work only for emails from journeys, is there a way to see all eblast sent?

Thanks!
L

Comment: that link you provided tells you what sends qualify Tracking information will be sent to Salesforce only if you're sending the emails to Salesforce Data Extensions and your subscriber key is the Salesforce Contact ID.  and then also JB sends with the box checked

Comment: The send was sent with a filtered data extension from the Lead object, should it works the same way?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_salesforce_data_extensions.htm&type=5